# CakePHP - JQuery Problem

Tags: cakephp

I am having some issues with JQuery and CakePHP. I wanted to know if JQuery will work the same way if I have 2 files that call the following function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

I have a Featured Content Slider that uses JQuery to Switch contents in a slider, but when I try to create another JQuery file, it does not work. Not even a simple alert.

Is that what is happening or is it something totally different, that perhaps I am overlooking?

Based on the fact that the Slider works, I have to believe I am including the JQuery file correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You can have multiple functions bound to the document's ready event. Something else must be wrong - you'll have to post more of your code so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is fine. jQuery will fire all the `ready()` functions at the same time with no issue. The issue you is in how you're including it not the number of functions.

post some cakephp code and i'll see if I can help